# How can I make a single-file script with Elixir, without excess output?

Tags: elixir

I would like to do something that seems like it should be simple, namely make a script that outputs a greeting message and nothing else. This script is so simple that it shouldn't require more than one file. Here's what I tried:

```
[ ~/elixir ] cat hello.exs
#!/usr/bin/env iex
IO.puts "Hello world!"
:init.stop

[ ~/elixir ] ./hello.exs
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Hello world!
Interactive Elixir (1.0.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> [ ~/elixir ]
```

This is pretty close to the desired result, but I'm looking for something like a --quiet or --silent flag to suppress the Erlang and Elixir startup messages. Adding the -S flag to iex doesn't help:

```
[ ~/elixir ] cat hello.exs
#!/usr/bin/env iex -S
IO.puts "Hello world!"
:init.stop

[ ~/elixir ] ./hello.exs
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

-S : Could not find executable ./hello.exs
```

I know it's possible (http://goo.gl/MtFTQF) to use mix to create a project for this, but it seems like overkill. All I want to do right now is make a simple hello script.

Comment: To amplify on José's answer: "elixir hello.exs" should give you what you're looking for.  By the way you don't need the :init.stop in your script either although I don't think it hurts or helps either way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the `elixir` executable to run Elixir files (`#!/usr/bin/env elixir`). `iex` will execute the file and start the Interactive Shell.